# ASIHTTPRequest help with setup on iPhone SDK?

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, asihttprequest

I have created a new project in Xcode and performed the following to add ASIHTTPRequest:

- Copied these files into the main project folder

  - ASIHTTPRequestConfig.h
  - ASIHTTPRequestDelegate.h
  - ASIProgressDelegate.h
  - ASICacheDelegate.h
  - ASIHTTPRequest.h
  - ASIHTTPRequest.m
  - ASIDataCompressor.h
  - ASIDataCompressor.m
  - ASIDataDecompressor.h
  - ASIDataDecompressor.m
  - ASIFormDataRequest.h
  - ASIInputStream.h
  - ASIInputStream.m
  - ASIFormDataRequest.m
  - ASINetworkQueue.h
  - ASINetworkQueue.m
  - ASIDownloadCache.h
  - ASIDownloadCache.m
  - ASIAuthenticationDialog.h
  - ASIAuthenticationDialog.m
  - Reachability.h (in the External/Reachability folder)
  - Reachability.m (in the External/Reachability folder)
- I have then dragged those files onto the right side of the project window
- I then go, Project -> Edit Active Target, click the + button, and **[problem 1]  "CFNetwork.framework"" is not there?**

I now want to add a new view controller and make the following code work;

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/script.php?first_name=%@",first_name] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request startSynchronous];
NSError *error = [request error];
NSString *response = nil;
if (!error) {

    response = [request responseString];

    NSLog(@"%@",response);

} else {

    return NO;

}
```

- I add a new UIViewController Subclass file
- I insert the code as above and **[problem 2] it says that 'first_name' is undefined and a bunch of other errors.**

How can I go about resolving both issues? And is there anything I am doing wrong which will hinder this from working as I expect? (Posting a variable to a PHP file, using a textfield and submit button)

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Xcode you are using?

Comment: @Gomathi: Xcode v3.2.6 64-bit

Comment: Anyhow, u have fixed the problem. So no need of the Xcode version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Xcode4.

Click Project in project navigator.
**Project** -> Select **Target** -> Select **Build phases** -> Expand **Link Binary with Libraries** -> Click **+**. You will find the framework.

And you have not declared the variable first_name.

Comment: Awesome! That fixed it, thank you! Now the next problem - do I just add a new view controller, paste in my code and it should run without a hiccup? No idea how to declare the variable or any other issues which may occur when running the above as is. Thanks again!